# how to make routing URL for our wish in zendframework using routes.ini file?

Tags: zend-framework, routes, zend-route

I need to the routing URL like the following

http://www.website.com/module-name/controller-name/{article-name}/{article-id}

i tried using the routes.ini file but it's not working

```
routes.index-latest.route = "index/latest/$1/:id"
routes.index-latest.module = "index"
routes.index-latest.defaults.controller = "latest"
routes.index-latest.defaults.action = "index"
routes.index-latest.defaults.id = ""
```

can you anyone suggest me on the issues or please tell me any other way to achieve the URL like through bootstrap file.

i searched on the net but i am not getting the right solution.

Comment: i fixed myself using the following way                    routes.index-latest.route = "index/latest/:article_id"
routes.index-latest.defaults.module = "module-name"
routes.index-latest.defaults.controller = "controller-name"
routes.index-latest.defaults.action = "index"
routes.index-latest.defaults.article_id = "\d+{1,}"
routes.index-latest.defaults.reqs.article_id = "\d+{1,}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed myself like example @

```
routes.index-latest.route = "index/latest/:article_id" 
routes.index-latest.defaults.module = "module-name" 
routes.index-latest.defaults.controller = "controller-name" 
routes.index-latest.defaults.action = "action-name" 
routes.index-latest.defaults.article_id = "" 
routes.index-latest.defaults.reqs.article_id = "\d+{1,}"
```

in routes.ini